# Another tourist Schengen visa after the previous one in 2 months?

Tags: visas, schengen

So I have stayed in Schengen zone for 25 days last month.
My visa is expiring soon. Now I want to go for another trip in two months and apply for another Schengen visa for 10 days.

Is there a problem in there? 
Is there a "cool-down" period between two Schengen visas or it doesn't matter?

Comment: What is your nationality and which kind of visa, if possible also for which countries do you want to get it.

Comment: The big rule you need to worry about is [the 90-in-180 rule](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/13183/3221).

Answer (score 3):

There is no cool-down period between visas but a [90 days in any 180 day maximum stay rule](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13183/about-schengen-90-180-rule), which does amount to a kind of cool-down period *between stays*.

Note that this rule also applies across multiple visas, which is why no other restriction is really necessary. It's not a problem for you since you have only stayed for 25 days so far but if you had already used up your 90 days and wanted to travel before the end of the relevant 180-day period, you could not get a new visa.

Comment: The last sentence isn't entirely true.  A traveler could have stayed in the Schengen area for 90 days in August, September, and October, and apply for a visa in January for a visit in February.  Such an application should not be denied because of the 90/180 rule.

Comment: @phoog I was trying to avoid getting into the details but I have tried to reformulate it to avoid the imprecision.